# Build a dynamic client list in build time

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm struggling to find a solution for the following issue:

Let's say I have a 'server' process in Kernel that centralize reports from all 'client' processes that signed up on it. This 'server' process will report other CPUs in the system when all 'client' processes finished their boot and they are ready.

A 'client' in my example will be any process in my system that wish to sign as one that 'server' needs to wait until he'll finish booting.

My problem is that the entire process above most be done in **build** time, because otherwise I am vulnerable to race cases, such as the following example:

Let's say my 'server' process finished his initial boot and he is ready, and he was the first process to boot in the system. In that case, if another CPU will query him - he will response that all 'clients' are ready (even if no one listed). So when other 'clients' will boot and list on it - it will be too late.

I want to build a generic solution, so once I finished building my environment - the 'server' process will 'know' how many 'clients' should sign up during system boot.

Any ideas here?

Thank you all

Comment: I fail to see the issue, do what you just wrote. Are you asking what a multiple producer single consumer container is?

Comment: I will try to explain - The issue is that I want my 'service' process to know in build time, how many 'client' processes are listed, but without sharing any data in front. So if a 'client' wants to add itself to the service, he will add a 'MACRO' (for example) and the 'service' will know to add it

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have understood:

- you want to build a *service* that will report whether other *clients* are up or not
- you want the list of clients to be dynamic - ie a client could register or unregister at will
- you want the list of clients to be persistent - the service should know the current list of clients immediately after each boot

A common way for that kind of requirement is to use a persistent *database* where the client can register (add one line) or unregister (delete their own line). The service has then only to read the database at boot time or on each request.

You cant then decide :

- whether you want to use a simple file, a lite database (SQLite) or a full database (PosgreSQL, MariaDB, ...)
- whether you want to read the database on each and every query or have the server *cache* the current state
- in case of caching, whether you can accept non accurate responses, and just refresh state when it is older than n seconds, or if you need immediate synchronization (database is read at boot, but registration goes to service that writes database back to persistent storage) - that last way is more accurate but registration is only possible when service is up

Depending on you actual requirements, you can then imagine more clever solutions, but above should help you to start

Comment: So the database is being build during compilation? and in run-time the server only reads it and follow?

Comment: If it is known at compilation time, just use a `define` parameter `-dclients=A,B,C` and parse it at beginning of main. But I must admit I have not understood why this should run in kernel, nor why you want do define that at build time...